# microsoft-teams creating meeting statistics from past meetings

Tags: api, microsoft-teams

I'm looking to create some statistics of past meetings with the end goal of getting average meetings per day, avg participants per meeting and an avg meeting duration. Planning on doing this for my organization, any helpful link to documentation, a similar question or any form of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Our team is working on it, currently we don't have any ETA o share with you. This item remains on the backlog in Teams UserVoice,
Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com).